# jqgrid: Exit edit mode programmatically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with a custom save function.

User can change data inline and on click of save, I get the edited rows and columns and create JSON to post to server.

getRowData returns the cell content, which in edit mode, is the html element. I want a way to exit the edit mode before using the getRowData method to get the actual data.

Is there any way to cancel the edit mode for the entire grid which I can call before the save. I can't use the saveRow functionality of jqgrid as there is a lot of custom code which needs to be written for creating the save JSON.

I am using jqgrid version v5.0.0

```
     grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#' + grid[0].id + '_toppager_left', { 
                caption: "",
                title: "Save",
                id: 'save' + gridName,
                onClickButton: function() {
               // I want to exit the edit mode here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by calling jqgrid's saveRow method to local array for all the edited rows before building my save JSON. This forced all rows out of edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

$('mySelector').jqGrid('restoreRow', capturedIdOfRowInEditMode);